# Wix install location

Tags: wix, installation, uninstallation, custom-action

I have a WIX setup that allows the user to select the install location. When uninstalling, I need to run a custom action that should activate a file in the install location. I tried getting the install location from `session["INSTALLDIR"]` but it results in the default path and not the one given by the user.

**How can I reach that location?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done this in my own installer - the following should work.

This adds a property to retrieve the install location value from the registry.

```
<Property Id="INSTALLDIR">
    <RegistrySearch Id='Registry' Type='raw' Root='HKCU' Key='Software\$(var.Manufacturer)\$(var.ProductName)' Name='Location' />
</Property>
```

This sets the install location in the registry.

```
<Component Id="Registry" Guid="*">
    <RegistryKey Root="HKCU" Key="Software\$(var.Manufacturer)\$(var.ProductName)">
        <RegistryValue Name="Location" 
                       Type="string" 
                       Value="[INSTALLDIR]" 
                       Action="write" 
                       KeyPath="yes" />
    </RegistryKey>
    <util:RemoveFolderEx On="uninstall" Property="INSTALLDIR" />
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want INSTALLDIR for a later time such as uninstallation you should use Remember property pattern described in link below.

"The root issue is that the Windows Installer does not save Property values for you. That means if the user enters values in the install UI or passes them on the command-line, those values will be not be present during repair, upgrade nor uninstall."

http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/the-wix-toolsets-remember-property-pattern/

Comment: I added the registry value but I can't manage to populate it correctly. How do I set the install dir into the property?